# With ARC, do I still need to follow the old retain release style?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Pre-ARC, this was how you set values to your properties to avoid memory leaks:

```
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
self.dictionary = tempDict;
[tempDict release];
```

But now with arc, do we still need to use the 2 line style, or can we just use a single line setter?

```
self.dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
```

versus

```
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
self.dictionary = tempDict;
```

Also, in general iOS dev, is it safe to just use properties most of the time, no more using the instance variables directly?

Comment: Why even two line in the first place?  A good developer balances his allocs with releases in dealloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the single-line style.

Perhaps I don't know what you mean by "safe".  Under ARC you can be sure that objects will be properly retained and released whether you use properties, instance variables, or a mixture.

Without ARC, it's usually safer (as in, less prone to human error) to always use property setters to ensure that objects are correctly retained and released.